# Thread local boost fast_pool_allocator

Tags: multithreading, c++11, boost, allocator, thread-local-storage

I've a multithreaded (Cilk) program where each thread use a temporary
`std::set`. There are a lot of allocations on these `std::set` so that I'm
trying to use some pool allocators namely `boost::fast_pool_allocator`:

```
using allocator = boost::fast_pool_allocator< SGroup::type >;
using set = std::set<SGroup::type, std::less<SGroup::type>, allocator>;
```

But now the performances are much worse because of concurrent access to the
allocator. One crucial fact is that the sets are never communicated among the
threads so that I can use a thread local allocators. However, as shown in the
previous code, I'm not constructing allocator objects but passing template
parameters to the `std::set` constructor.

So here is my question: is it possible to construct multiple
`boost::fast_pool_allocator` to use them as thread local pool allocator ?

**Edit** : I removed stupid `std::pair` allocations.

Comment: Why do you use `T = std::pair<const SGroup::type, const SGroup::type>`? Your set contains SGroup::type objects.

Comment: Because otherwise the code doesn't compile ;-(... I got some error message `error: ‘static const value_type* boost::fast_pool_allocator<T, UserAllocator, Mutex, NextSize, MaxSize>::address(boost::fast_pool_allocator<T, UserAllocator, Mutex, NextSize, MaxSize>::const_reference)` [...] cannot be overloaded. Not sure where is the problem though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I actually have to pass a `std::pair` but I can give whatever as the second member. I guess `set` are actually implemented as maps with a unused value.

Comment: Forget about that, I was just confused...

Comment: @hivert What was the fix for this? I am having the exact same questions / issue. Can you please post an answer to this if one was found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Mmm. I had an answer here that I pieced together from things I remembered seeing. However, upon further inspection it looks like all the allocators actually work with Singleton Pools that are **never** thread safe without synchronization. In fact, the `null_mutex` is likely in a `detail` namespace *for this very reason*: it only makes sense to use it if you know the program doesn't use threads (well, outisde the main thread) *at all*.

Aside from this apparent debacle, you could probably use [`object_pool`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html#boost_pool.pool.interfaces.interfaces.object_pool) directly. But it's not an allocator, so it wouldn't serve you for your container example.

---

*Original Answer Text*:

You can pass an allocator instance at construction:

```
#include <boost/pool/pool.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <set>

struct SGroup
{
    int data;
    typedef int type;
};

using allocator = boost::fast_pool_allocator<SGroup::type>;
using set = std::set<SGroup::type, std::less<SGroup::type>, allocator>;

void thread_function()
{
    allocator alloc; // thread local
    set myset(set::key_compare(), alloc);

    // do stuff
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread_group group;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i)
        group.create_thread(thread_function);

    group.join_all();
}
```

Let me read the docs on how to disable thread-awareness on the allocator :)

Found it in an example:

```
typedef boost::fast_pool_allocator<SGroup::type,
   boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete,
   boost::details::pool::null_mutex> allocator;
```

The example in `boost/libs/pool/example/time_pool_alloc.hpp` should help you get started benchmarking the difference(s) in performance

Comment: Undeleted answer with new insights.

Comment: @sehe : Thanks for this clarification. That's probably explain, why I'm getting segfault at random places as soon as I have more that 1 thread. Anyway, I leave my +1 to thank you for your research and help.